Access elements inside closed shadow DOM
Is there any possible way to access elements inside closed shadow DOM using Puppeteer?
I understand that the point of closed shadow DOM is for the items not to be accessible, but since Puppeteer is used to scrape webpages, I think it would be reasonable that we can access it using Puppeteer.
I tried accessing elements inside a closed shadow DOM using Puppeteer but I couldn't do it.
Example:
A simple webpage I'm trying to extract:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
   class ContainerComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();

    const containerTemplate = document.createElement("template");
    containerTemplate.innerHTML = `
       <slot></slot>
       <div>This is what I want</div>
    `;
  
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "closed" });
    shadowRoot.appendChild(containerTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}

customElements.define("layout-container", ContainerComponent);
  </script>

  <layout-container>
  </layout-container>
</body>
</html>

import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

async function start() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/iframe-test-nested.html");

  const result = await page.$("body layout-container");

  if (!result) {
    console.log("Element not found");
  } else {
    const innerHTML = await page.evaluate(
      (el) => el.shadowRoot?.innerHTML,
      result
    );
    console.log(innerHTML);
  }

  await browser.close();
}

start();


Or even using >>> selector:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

async function start() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://localhost:8080/iframe-test-nested.html");

  const result = await page.$("body layout-container >>> div");

  if (!result) {
    console.log("Element not found");
  } else {
    const innerHTML = await page.evaluate((el) => el.innerHTML, result);
    console.log(innerHTML);
  }

  await browser.close();
}

start();

Thanks in advance.

Related: How to automate webpage under a closed shadowDOM, Need help to click on the element under the shadow Root (closed) type, How can I Fill an Input with "Shadow Root (closed)" using Puppeteer?. I think the answer is "you can't".

This question is similar to: How to automate webpage under a closed shadowDOM. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe the base question should be; should you test a component when used in an application? Do you test the tires and all other components when you buy a new car?

OP may be scraping, not testing.

Puppeteer's queries the page using DOM APIs so it generally currently cannot access closed shadow roots with one exception. ARIA selectors are based on the browser accessibility tree can return references to elements inside closed shadow roots (over CDP). The caveat is that the element needs to be included into the accessibility tree to be found (and not every element is included). You can also use accessibility tree snapshots to get the whole tree with all accessible content at once (iframe support is limited). The accessibility tree provides the information that usually screen reader software sees so it is useful when testing a11y or writing tests that do not rely on specific DOM structure.
Also, note that although ARIA selectors give access to elements inside closed shadow roots, I am not sure how well it works with other Puppeteer APIs.
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    class ContainerComponent extends HTMLElement {
        constructor() {
            super();

            const containerTemplate = document.createElement("template");
            containerTemplate.innerHTML = \`
            <slot></slot>
            <div role="button">This is what I want</div>
            \`; // Changed role to button to make element searchable.
        
            const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "closed" });
            shadowRoot.appendChild(containerTemplate.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    customElements.define("layout-container", ContainerComponent);
  </script>
  <layout-container>
  </layout-container>
</body>
</html>`;

import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent(html);
const result = await page.$("aria/This is what I want");
console.log("Element exists", !!result); // true
console.log(await result.evaluate(el => el.getRootNode({composed:false}).mode)) // 'closed'
await browser.close();

